# How do I view the dependency tree for Gradle's buildSrc?

Tags: gradle

I can normally view a dependency tree for a project by running `./gradlew dependencies`, but I cannot figure out how to view the dependency tree for the Gradle buildSrc directory.

I have tried accessing it as a sub project, `./gradlew buildSrc:dependencies` but that does not work.

build.gradle (for buildSrc)

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following (the only way that I know of):

```
$ cd buildSrc
$ gradle dependencies
```

Note, given your `build.gradle` example, that `buildSrc` is its own project in Gradle and needs a proper file. Your example doesn't declare any plugins. Assuming you are using Java, a fix is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I get an error for that `Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19] on root project 'buildSrc'.
`

Comment: Your buildSrc/build.gradle isn't valid because it doesn't apply any plugins. I have put an example in the answer.